# Access the element inner html and attribute values inside controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html content as,

```
<div ng-controller="logCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="logMe" someAttr="hello ricky">hello martin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript content as,

```
var app = angular.module('app',  []);
app.controller('logCtrl',  function ($scope, $element) {
  $scope.logMe = function(){
    console.log("html content is " + /*---- how can i print $element's inner html text here --- */)
    console.log("attribute value is " + /*---- how can i read the li element's someAttr value here --- */)
  }
})
```

This must print this message in the console (when user clicks the mouse),

```
html content is hello martin
attribute value is hello ricky
```

Comment: you can use jQuery to do that.. <li ng-click="logMe" someAttr="hello ricky" id="test">hello martin</li>  $('#test').html() and $('#test').attr('someAttr');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**HTML**

```
 <li ng-click="logMe($event)" someAttr="hello ricky">hello martin</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.logMe = function(e){
    var value=e.target.attributes.someAttr.value;
}
```